# Creating value arrays in keys of merged objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, assign

With javascript I am trying to compare values in nested JSON objects. I would like to merge the objects using the Object.assign() method but generate arrays of values. If a key/value pair is not found in one of the objects the array should contain a null;

For example I have these 3 input objects:

```
let O1 = [
    { "group1": { "attr1": 1 } },
    { "group2": { "attr1": 2 } }
]

let O2 = [
    { "group2": { "attr1": 3 } },
    {
        "group3": {
            "attr1": 4,
            "attr2": 5
        }
    }
]

let O3 = [
    { "group1": { "attr1": 6 } },
    { "group3": { "attr1": 7 } }
]
```

And I want to merge these into this new object:

```
let result = [
    { "group1": { "attr1": [1, null, 6] } },
    { "group2": { "attr1": [2, 3, null] } },
    {
        "group3": {
            "attr1": [null, 4, 7],
            "attr2": [null, 5, null]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: could you please explain the logic behind these Arrays.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You can use a conditional expression like `(O2[groupname] && O2[groupname][attrname]) ? O2[groupname][attrname]) : null`

Comment: maybe you rething the naming of the properties. it is more complicated to use dynamic keys.

Comment: It's not homework. It's for an open source project I am working on. The logic behind these arrays is that I am working on application in which I want to compare two or more items. The applications is here http://geolytix.co.uk/map?seamless_locales

Comment: If you select a neighbourhood you see the properties of that neighbourhood. I want to create a table in which I have one item in a column and the numeric records in a single row in order to compare them.

Comment: @Barmar; I can replace the example with real data which has hundreds of nested properties, I don't see how that will help to explain the problem?! And of course I am working on a solution by myself If I would have the answer to this problem I would not need to ask this question.

Comment: The part about homework is just my boilerplate, it doesn't necessarily mean this is homework (but it it were, we wouldn't do it for you). And if you're working on a solution, show what you tried. What I wrote uses variables, so it works for any number of different properties. If the nesting level can be deeper, use a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const result = [];

  for(var [index, array] of [O1, O2, O3].entries()){
     for(var [arrayIndex, obj] of array.entries()){
        (function copy(obj, res){
           for(var [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
              if(typeof value === "object"){
                 copy(value, res[key] || (res[key] = {}));
              } else {
                 if(!res[key]) res[key] = [];
                 res[key][index] = value;
             }
          }
        })(obj, result[arrayIndex] || (result[arrayIndex] = {}));
     }
  }
```

So long story short: change your datastructure...

Comment: Put the executable version here in a stack snippet instead of linking to jsbin.com.

Comment: I am just about to create a jsfiddle in which I can post the real data.

Comment: @barmar we had that topic a few times already ;) 1) i dont want to copy the OPs data into my answer. 2) i cant hit the `<>` button as its not displayed on my device :/

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I should be able to get there from what you posted. I created  a fiddle in which I use the more complex test data and already added a check for numeric values as it won't make sense to compare the text elements in my output table. https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/1hmLeexs/

Comment: @JonasW., why not use stack snippets for a working presentation?

Comment: @nina see two comments above :/

Comment: @JonasW. you could copy the needed frame from another answer and use it with your code.

Comment: @nina its definetly possible somehow but i think good code could be verified by looking at it, i dont like this "click here, copy the code, accept as answer, done" , i want the OPs to read through the code and to at least partly understand it.